# Windows Service and Task Factory

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, task-parallel-library, taskfactory

I have experience of developing windows service where different methods are executed on different time interval using different timer for each method. However i have recently came across to one windows service which doing same thing using System.Threading.Tasks and ManualResetEvent. I don't have much knowledge of these. Following is the code that demonstrate how the windows service is created. I have included only onstart and methods which are executed. I checked in console application and tasks are not getting blocked because of waitone. But as i have said i don't have much technical knowledge of task so i need some opinion whether following approach is correct or wrong for window service where different methods are executed on different intervals.

```
Private Shared mReset As New ManualResetEvent(False)

Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)

        Try
            mReset.Reset()

            Dim task1 As Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(New Action(AddressOf Task1), TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness)

            Dim task2 As Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(New Action(AddressOf Task2), TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness)    

        Catch ex As Exception
            'Throw ex
            WriteMessage(ex.Message)
        End Try
End Sub



 Private Sub Task1()
        Try
            Dim WaitTime As Integer = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
            While Not mReset.WaitOne(WaitTime)
                Try
                    ' Perform Some Task Daily
                Catch ex As Exception
                    WriteMessage(ex.Message)
                    WriteMessage(ex.StackTrace.ToString)
                End Try

            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
            WriteMessage(ex.Message)
            WriteMessage(ex.StackTrace.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Task2()
        Try

            While Not mReset.WaitOne(60000)

                Try
                    'Perform some operation per minute
                Catch ex As Exception
                    WriteMessage(ex.Message)
                    WriteMessage(ex.StackTrace.ToString)
                End Try

            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
            WriteMessage(ex.Message)
            WriteMessage(ex.StackTrace.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: If you don't have a specific question, this might be more suited for Code Review?

Comment: @svick i just only want to know if i develop windows service as above it will block any task until other get completed. as i mentioned one is executed per day and other is executed per minute.  So both task will run on separate thread or on same thread?